# Including File PHP not work - work by using comment tag - bug?

Tags: php, tags

**ISSUE:**

> PHP Warning: ........ failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home/.

I found many titles discussed related on the topic I pick now. I tried to look into the path and make sure everything went okay. I also checked the server connectivity, bandwidth or everything related to hosting or DNS stuff and tried it again. But it was still not working.
However, when I use php comment tag, as in `#`, unbelievable, it really really works! That's why I want to find out why it could be like that.

*Here's the actual path:*

> /home/appacybe/public_html/in-grammar/user_validator.php on line 2

**Previous (error) report codes:**

```
<?php
include('../user_validator.php');
...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
</html>
```

**Working codes:**

**index.php:**

```
<?php
################# start ####################
############################################
#################  end  ####################
include('../user_validator.php');
...
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--bla bla
./end -->
```

**Inside user_validator.php:**

```
<?php
echo 'hallo';
?>
```

**Successfully Output:**

```
- Hallo
- other text below it.
```

Some suggests to use **[Magic Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)** and many says that I should use `require`, `require_once` or others.
But when I use that php commentary tag, I found it works successfully.
What's wrong? Is this a bug? or I just don't know how to be on the right PHP programming?

Please let me know.

This is the simple thing for you perhaps but really I still question; what's wrong with it or "me" ?

**NEW POSSIBILITIES:**
I tested to VPS or Dedicated Server and it works by using common function. But always got failed in share hosting - but working with the comment tag.
What's going on? :(

Any help would be so great!

Comment: File encoding? (Linebreaks?) Why should that file reside in /home? Can it generate output when preceded with the comment block? More context.

Comment: Could you show is raw file?

Comment: I really don't know it. I just need to include the user_validator.php and test it, I just give a line of sentence,e.g. <?php echo 'hallo'; ?> inside user_validator.php to test it and that's all and the error said like that .

Answer (score 1):

You can use dirname(**FILE**) to obtain the path of the script that line is called in. You can then reference relative paths from there e.g.

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . '../user_validator.php');
```

According to me, In some cases where $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not set or is not what you would expect (i.e. not set in CLI or old IIS, or invalid in certain CGI setups) then server might not be able to find out related path of include file. So, it will give an error.

Comment: thanks for your response. I use magic constant too. but it got failed. It works by using comment tag, so pls read again my question.

Comment: Have you tried different variations like this..?? --> 1] include(user_validator.php);  2] include "/user_validator.php"; 3] include("../user_validator.php"); 4] include("./user_validator.php"); 5] include(../in-grammar/user_validator.php)